# Twincat3 ST variables conversion

Tags: string, csv, type-conversion, twincat, st

I have some complicated array of structures and I want to write it into CSV file. So I need "variable to string" conversion.
Beckhoff as always doesn't care about documentation and their INT_TO_STRING function doesn't work (UNEXPECTED INT_TO_STRING TOKEN when I try to write INT_TO_STRING(20) ).
Moreover their string functions works correctly with only 255 chars.

So I need one of following:

- working functions or function blocks or library which allows to convert different types to string
- something like sprintf without limitations
- some functions to convert between number and ascii char (0x55 is letter 'U') in both directions.

btw. Beckhoff gives us some weird CSV example code, but without data conversion (array has already strings in cells).

Thanks in advance!

I tried to use:
`INT_TO_STRING() BYTE_TO_STRING() WHATEVER_TO_STRING()`

but it is not working. And there is no clue how many arguments it should have or anything. There is no documentation in *Beckhoff information System*.

Comment: `INT_TO_STRING()` should work, you are probably using it wrong. You can also usually use shorthand `TO_STRING()` too. Please add code or some example. There is help available in [Beckhoff infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3998090635.html&id=).

Comment: I made huge mistake. In main file I usually write some variables at the bottom, which I want to see during debugging.
`sTest1;
iValue2;
aData[3];
`
 Its easier, when you want to see specific data from array of structures. And this time I forgot, that TO_STRING should be assigned to something.
`TO_STRING(20);` 
doesn't work, but 
`sSomeString := TO_STRING(20);`
works correctly.

But is there some possibility to convert to string but into hex or bin value? 
`sTest := TO_STRING(16#55);`
is converted to decimal number 85;

Comment: I don't want to be rude but please try to Google first before asking here, there is lot's of information available. You can use [Tc2_Utilities library function WORD_TO_HEXSTR](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/934165003.html&id=) to convert to hex number and `WORD_TO_BINSTR` for binary conversion.

Comment: Thank you a lot. And you're right. I should ask google, but I'm rather embedded programmer, not PLC, and I was googling for something more similar to my world like formatting in printf (%3f, %x) or hex2dec.
So Thank you one more time :)

Comment: No problem, feel free to create new questions! The TwinCAT/Codesys knowledge here in stack overflow is increasing all the time. If searching something for twincat, usually searches like "twincat to string hex" searches work nice.